# Зачем нужны метки "указатели", "массивы", "функции", "классы"?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Зачем нужны метки [указатели](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8), [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b), [функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8), [классы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b)?

Часто авторы вопросов добавляют эти теги по принципу "что вижу - о том и пою". Если в коде есть указатель, массив, и функция - то они добавляют эти теги. Странно что еще не догадался добавить метку "точка-с-запятой".

В каких ситуациях эти теги могут быть действительно полезны?

Comment: Массивы - в сочетании с алгоритмами. Ну а указатели я бы вообще не трогал.

Answer (score 4):

Метка [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b) дает возможность поискать что-нибудь по этой метке + метке конкретного языка. Неплохо, если SO используется в режиме обучения — «А что можно почитать хорошего про массивы в языке X?». Аналогичные метки — про другие структуры данных: [список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba), [дерево](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be), [бинарное-дерево](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be) и т.п.

Аналогично с меткой [указатели](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8). Я думаю, что она имеет смысл. Точнее могут сказать специалисты по языкам, где есть операции с указателями.

А вот что касается [функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8), [классы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b), [переменные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5), [точка-с-запятой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9), [отступ-в-четыре-пробела](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0), [переменная-i-в-цикле-for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-i-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-for)  — в них не вижу пользы. Эти элементы обычно есть в любом коде (понятно, что классы — в ооп). Вряд ли можно задать такой вопрос, чтобы для него не нашлось более осмысленной метки.

Comment: Те вопросы "про массивы", которые про алгоритмы - на самом деле это последовательности или про контейнеры с произвольным доступом, т.к. алгоритму все равно с чем работать, с массивом или нет. Оставшиеся вопросы - это вопросы про язык "как в С++ проинициализировать массив", "можно ли сделать массив нулевой длины". Для вопросов про язык метка "массив" не нужна, также как и метка "переменная", "конструктор" или "функция".

Comment: @Abyx: хорошо, убедили.

Comment: точка-с-запятой, отступ-в-четыре-пробела, переменная-i-в-цикле-for вот в них реально мало смысла.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы подобные теги удалил. Все вопросы по классам, если уж очень хочется, можно отнести к [ооп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%be%d0%bf).

[указатели](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8), [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b), [функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8) весьма, хм, сложные метки. В том смысле, что очень зависят от конкретного языка. Поэтому, как таковые, метки эти являют собой солянки какие-то.

Comment: Из списка `указатели`, `массивы`, `функции`, `классы` только классы имеют непосредственное отношение к `ООП`.