# Метка "массивы" - нужна ли она

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Вот уже который день вижу в очереди предлагаемых правок [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/491569/revisions), добавляющие к разным вопросам метку [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b).

Это личная инициатива отдельных участников - или я что-то пропустил?

Обсуждений этой метки на Мете я нашел всего [одно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2239/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B) - и там выступлений в защиту метки не нашлось.

Но, тем не менее, у этой метки есть описание и два синонима - значит, она кому-то нужна? Так что с ней делать?

Comment: Я лично против настолько низкоуровневых меток. Массивы, переменные, скобки, функции — это всё базовые элементы языка. Хотел написать ответ, но он по сути совпадал бы с вопросом, который вы привели как пример обсуждения.

Comment: Если удалять, то только через черный список. Иначе на следующий день снова будет эта метка.

Comment: Я тоже против того, чтобы лепить ее везде, где упоминаются массивы.

Comment: так меток миллион, неужели можно помнить какие можно, какие - нет? Новичкам на это вовсе пофиг.

Comment: @Jean-Claude новички нередко лепят на вопрос метки [ошибка][программирование][проблема][помогите]. Поскольку пользы от этих меток никакой, мы их вычищаем/удаляем/запрещаем.