# Уточнение оснований использования меток [массивы] и [алгоритмы]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, правки

По мотивам комментариев к [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1173362/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-csv-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83), где произошёл конфликт мнений относительно использования меток.

Автор вопроса использовал метки "массивы" и "алгоритмы".

На мой взгляд - необосновано, так как суть вопроса не имеет отношения ни к массивам, ни к алгоритмам. Поэтому я удалил эти метки.

Пользователь [Vasily](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/397819/vasily) с этим не согласился и вернул метки. По его мнению, раз вопрос состоит в том, чтобы из массива получить строку, то использование метки "массив" вполне обосновано.

Мне кажется, что это неверный подход.
На мой взгляд, такое использование меток противоречит цели данного механизма - поиску и определению вопросов, которые интересуют человека и/или относятся к его специализации.
Я не могу себе представить, чтобы кто-то намеренно использовал метку "массивы", чтобы найти вопросы, в которых из исходных данных, находящихся в массиве автор хочет получить какой-либо результат.

Мне казалось очевидным, что метку "массивы" следует использовать только для вопросов, сосредоточенных на нюансах использования и реализации массивов, которые не имеют жёсткой привязки к конкретному языку. В вопросах же, где автору нужна последовательность функций и методов конкретного языка, чтобы получить из определённого массива определённый результат, на мой взгляд, не следует использовать такую метку.

Однако Vasily счёл это совсем не очевидным, и указал мне на то, что в описании метки нет такой конкретики.

Что касается метки "алгоритм", то, на мой взгляд, ей вообще по жизни не везёт. Начинающие программисты, которым на уроках информатики объяснили, что "алгоритм" - это последовательность действий для решения конкретной задачи, задают вопросы из серии "Подскажите алгоритм, как прочитать данные из файла и записать в другой файл". Хотя я более чем уверен, что люди, которые отслеживают эту метку, ожидают увидеть только вопросы по теории алгоритмов и стандартным алгоритмам (сортировки, алгоритмы на графах, криптографические алгоритмы и т.п.)

Читал раздел справки о метках, но ничего конкретного по этому вопросу не нашёл.

Прошу дать разъяснение относительно того, как мне следует реагировать, если я вижу на вопросах такие бессмысленные (на мой взгляд) метки. Следует ли мне удалять их?

Так же предлагаю исправить описание меток "массивы" и "алгоритм" так, чтобы из них было очевидно, что их следует использовать во вполне конкретных ситуациях.

Comment: Алгоритмы там явно не в тему.

Comment: [tag:массивы] нормально, [tag:алгоритм] ненормально, потому что первую принято использовать где угодно (массивы используются в вопросе), а вторую — когда нужен именно алгоритм, часто без кода (обычно олимпиадные задачи или задачи с длинным текстовым описанием без кода)

Comment: Вынужден согласиться с вашим оппонентом (Vasily) - данный вопрос об обработке и трансформации массивов и метка [tag:массивы] на нем вполне уместна. Про алгоритмы - согласен.

Answer (score 9):

Конкретно метка "массивы" уже обсуждалась, и ставился вопрос о ее удалении ([Зачем нужны метки "указатели", "массивы", "функции", "классы"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2239/240512)). В итоге пришли к тому, чтобы ее оставить и использовать в смысле "относится к массивам". Определить, относится ли вопрос к нюансам реализации, беглым взглядом довольно трудно, поэтому был принят такой, более простой подход, чтобы было меньше споров и войн правок, которые генерируют шум в истории ревизий.

Это не значит, что надо бросаться везде, где есть слово "массивы", ее добавлять, правка должна быть существенной. Здесь Vasily добавил эту метку вместе с другими улучшениями, исправлением опечаток и форматирования, поэтому это было оправданно. Если вы видите, что участник создает много правок только с добавлением таких "незначительных" меток, то можно порекомендовать ему прекратить делать это.